# how to make datetimepicker readonly in struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts

I am using datatimepicker in struts 2. But textfield is  editable. I want it in readonly. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript :**

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByName("dojo.test")[0].setAttribute("readOnly","true");
}
```

**Struts2 Tag :** 

`<sx:datetimepicker name="test" />`

Answer (score 0):

what kind of datepicker are you using. I was using dojo/datapicker and when tested in eclipse the values are reaching the action class but  when i tested on broswer out of eclipse and also server it was comming as null.

I wasted quite a lot of time on it and went back to normal textfield.

I know this is not relevant to you question but just please check.

And if you using any other datepicker which is not acting so weird please let me know i can use the same

thanks

Answer (score 0):

lschin's method worked for me. Just make a regular js function and call it on page body load.
If you have multiple elements with the same name you can call them as an array too..

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question.

Use following script. This will work in all browsers.

```
 < % @ taglib prefix="sd" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" % >
 <head>
   <sd:head/>
</head>
```

**Javascript:**

```
< script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('fromDate').children[1].setAttribute("readOnly","true");
};
</ script>
```

**Struts2 Tag :**

```
 <sd:datetimepicker  name="fromDate" id="fromDate" label="From Date" />
```

If any problem is there please let me know.